# graduate level introduction to elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am looking for a good modern book / lecture-notes about elliptic curve cryptography. Does anyone have good recommendations?

Comment: Stinson's "Cryptography - Theory and Practice" (chapter 6 deals with elliptic curves), Washington's "Elliptic Curves - Number Theory and Cryptography", (again, chapter 6), Enge's "Elliptic Curves and their Application to Cryptography"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil Koblitz, one of the major figures in the development of ECC, has a graduate level work on cryptography and some relevant sectors of number theory. Somewhat needless to say, it has an extended discussion of elliptic curves. The only thing to note is that it is from 1994, so it may be a bit dated in some places.

https://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-94293-3